# "React Native with Android aar library" ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.LazyKt

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, classnotfoundexception, aar

I’m using my own Android library that done on Kotlin.
I build that library into the *.aar file and import in separate project on React Native.
The crash appears in Android React Native app when I start Service from that library, where some field initialized by lazy way.

I could not find an error similar to "Lkotlin / LazyKt" or "kotlin.LazyKt". Maybe someone faced a similar problem? I would be grateful for any tip.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project_mobile:sdmp, PID: 18913
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/LazyKt;
    at com.project.service.SdmService.<init>(SdmService.kt:27)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.LazyKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.project_mobile-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.project_mobile-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.project_mobile-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.project.service.SdmService.<init>(SdmService.kt:27) 
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.LazyKt
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: Fix was found. In target project I used `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:1.2.10` that was wrong. Instead of it I set `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.10` and crash didn't appear.